# Oracle PIVOT monthly row data to 12 monthly columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose

I'm querying a table which has data as such:

```
ACT  CY  GRP   MONTH     AMT
111 CY15 AAA 2015-01-01  2.3
222 CY15 AAA 2015-01-01  3.1 
111 CY15 AAA 2015-02-01 11.5  
222 CY15 AAA 2015-02-01 44.6
111 CY15 AAA 2015-03-01  4.9
222 CY15 AAA 2015-03-01  3.8
222 CY15 AAA 2015-04-01    0  
111 CY15 AAA 2015-04-01 49.8
111 CY15 AAA 2015-05-01    0 
222 CY15 AAA 2015-05-01 83.0
111 CY15 AAA 2015-06-01    0 
222 CY15 AAA 2015-06-01 79.7
111 CY15 AAA 2015-07-01 66.4
222 CY15 AAA 2015-07-01    0 
222 CY15 AAA 2015-08-01 25.5
111 CY15 AAA 2015-08-01 63.1
222 CY15 AAA 2015-09-01 30.4
111 CY15 AAA 2015-09-01 79.7
111 CY15 AAA 2015-10-01 28.0
222 CY15 AAA 2015-10-01 66.4
222 CY15 AAA 2015-11-01 66.4
111 CY15 AAA 2015-11-01 28.3
111 CY15 AAA 2015-12-01 79.7
222 CY15 AAA 2015-12-01 30.5
333 CY16 AAA 2016-01-01 25.4
444 CY16 AAA 2016-01-01 63.1
444 CY16 AAA 2016-02-01 56.4
333 CY16 AAA 2016-02-01 20.2
444 CY16 AAA 2016-03-01 22.4
333 CY16 AAA 2016-03-01 59.8
333 CY16 AAA 2016-04-01 58.7
444 CY16 AAA 2016-04-01 19.5
333 CY16 AAA 2016-05-01 19.6
444 CY16 AAA 2016-05-01 58.7
444 CY16 AAA 2016-06-01 11.7
333 CY16 AAA 2016-06-01 70.4
333 CY16 AAA 2016-07-01 58.7
444 CY16 AAA 2016-07-01 19.5
444 CY16 AAA 2016-08-01 58.7
333 CY16 AAA 2016-08-01 19.3
333 CY16 AAA 2016-09-01 11.3
444 CY16 AAA 2016-09-01 70.4
333 CY16 AAA 2016-10-01 55.7
333 CY16 AAA 2016-11-01 14.3
333 CY16 AAA 2016-12-01 19.3
555 CY15 BBB 2015-01-01 58.7
555 CY15 BBB 2015-02-01 70.4
555 CY15 BBB 2015-03-01 13.6
555 CY15 BBB 2015-04-01 55.7
555 CY15 BBB 2015-05-01 49.8
555 CY15 BBB 2015-06-01 58.7
555 CY15 BBB 2015-07-01 65.9
555 CY15 BBB 2015-08-01 19.0
555 CY15 BBB 2015-09-01 15.9
555 CY15 BBB 2015-10-01 87.9
555 CY15 BBB 2015-11-01 83.5
555 CY15 BBB 2015-12-01 10.7
666 CY16 BBB 2016-01-01 87.9
666 CY16 BBB 2016-02-01 87.9
666 CY16 BBB 2016-03-01 15.4
666 CY16 BBB 2016-04-01 83.5
666 CY16 BBB 2016-05-01 74.7
666 CY16 BBB 2016-06-01 79.1
666 CY16 BBB 2016-07-01 47.9
666 CY16 BBB 2016-08-01 47.9
666 CY16 BBB 2016-09-01 57.5
666 CY16 BBB 2016-10-01 47.9
666 CY16 BBB 2016-11-01 47.9
666 CY16 BBB 2016-12-01 57.5
```

And I'm trying to display it as follows

```
GRP CY January February March ... December
AAA 15   5.4     56.1    AMT  ...    AMT
AAA 16   AMT     AMT     AMT  ...    AMT
BBB 15   AMT     AMT     AMT  ...    AMT
BBB 16   AMT     AMT     AMT  ...    AMT
```

WHERE AMT is the sum of all account amounts for that month in that group and same calendar year.

My first attempt

```
select * from (select p.grp, p.cy, p.month, p.amt from phasing p WHERE
p.act IN  ('111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666') ) pivot( sum(amt) 
FOR to_char(to_date(month, 'YYYY-DD-MM'), 'Month')
in 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April')    )
```

ORA-01738: missing IN keyword

This at least didn't error but I don't always know the `Month` dates

```
select * from (select p.grp, p.cy, p.month, p.amt from phasing p WHERE
p.act IN  ('111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666') ) pivot( sum(amt) 
FOR month in (to_date('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') As Jan, to_date('2015-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') As Feb)    )
```

I think I need a GROUP BY in my first attempt so that I am not summing all `Januarys` for every calendar year, but I couldn't even get that to work.

Comment: I find down votes useless unless followed with a comment why it was down voted. How is one to understand why it was a poorly formulated question and learn from their mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select act, cy,
       sum(case when to_char(month, 'MM') = '01' then amt end) as Jan,
       sum(case when to_char(month, 'MM') = '02' then amt end) as Feb,
       . . .,
       sum(case when to_char(month, 'MM') = '12' then amt end) as Dec
from phasing p
group by act, cy;
```

Comment: That is nice and clean! I added my where clause " from phasing p where act in ('111', etc) group by"... thanks!